# unable to see DataPower xml firewall logs

Tags: curl, ibm-datapower

Actually I have created one loopback xml firewall in IBM DataPower xi50 and it does  a transformation from JSON to SOAP.Now while I am testing it using CURL I do not get any output nor anything is there in 'show Probe'.What actually can be the reason for this behaviour.My CURL command is following

```
curl --data-binary @smallFile.txt https://DPIP:port -S
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your url has `https` and that's why you are getting the error. As you are using `-S` it doesn't return you any error(if you get any). Just remove the `-S` and you'll see the error.

Now, to fix that error(about `https`) you have to add `-k` parameter. It will solve your problem. So your overall command will be

```
curl --data-binary @smallFile.txt https://DPIP:port -S -k
```

Answer (score 0):

Probe settings only works if you have rule setup and it is hit. Since you are transforming the JSON into SOAP I assume you have the processing policy set for the XML FW. But can you ensure if the rule is actually getting hit. Secondly do you see any log on System Logs? Is the request type correctly set as JSON? If all of these are set as expected, can you create a '*' rule in processing policy so that it acts as default rule for processing and then see if you are able to see the probe. Ideally you should be able to see it.